# Need a way to access class instance and data by name in C#

Tags: c#, class, dynamic

I have a group of class instances (all of the same class) and groups of data in those instances.  The class is to store information about a real-world object.  Each instance represents a different physical object.  The class is nothing more than a group of lines like this:
public string strStageType { get; set; }
public float fltTankDepth { get; set; }

The property names are directly related to the control names from which the property value is taken.  For instance, text textbox "txtWire1" is stored in the class instance in a string variable called "strWire1".

What I need to do is this: If "object 1" is selected and "txtWire1.Text" is changed I need to set the value of "classInstance1.strWire1" to the value of "txtWire1.Text".  The problem is that I don't know the full class instance name until runtime.  I know "classInstance" part but the "1" the program finds out at runtime.  And I don't know the name of the property I want to access until the program knows which control had a property change.

I could do a bunch of If statements, doing 10 identical If statements, one for each instance of the class (there will always be 10), and then in those If statements do 65 additional If statements so that I could name the class and property explicitly, but that's a pointless amount of repeating code.  I would rather be able to do something like I do for controls in the code below:

```
TextBox txtLinkToControl = Controls.Find("txt" + stringSomeVariableContainingTheRest, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
```

This lets me link txtLinkToControl to txtWire1 or txtWire2, allowing me to build the name of what I want to access at runtime rather than add an If statement for every textbox control in my program or iterating through them one by one, allowing me to code access to "txtLinkToControl" when it's really accessing "txtWire1".

So, what I need is:

1. A way to access the class instance by name, which I can build at runtime with information about what is selected at the time and
2. A way to access a property of the above class instance by name, which I can build at runtime with information about what is changing.

Ideally the solution would allow me to do something like this (I know this code is not valid, it's a representation of what I want to do):

```
foreach (TextBox txtBox in this.Controls)
```

{

```
//NOTE: Class name is clsMyClass. Class instances are in the form of: clsMyClass classInstance1 = new clsMyClass;

//Set up the variables to determine the class instance and data to access
int intSelectedRepresentedObject = cmbSomeCombobox.SelectedIndes();//The specific object represented by one instance of clsMyClass
string strProperty = txtBox.Name.SubString(3, txtBox.Name.Length - 3);//The name of the textbox without the leading "txt", which matches the name of the property without the leading "str"

//Create a new "pointer" instance of clsMyClass, linking to the specific instance
clsMyClass clsCurrentInstance = Class.Find("classInstance" + intSelectedObject.ToString(), true);
clsCurrentInstance.FindProperty("str" + strProperty, true) = "Text to set in property";
```

}

If there's a better way to group a large amount of data of different types (currently 65 items of types string, integer, float and boolean) which will allow me to create multiple instance and access all of it easily, I'd be happy to hear it.  Nothing too complicated, though.  I don't care how efficient or "pretty" the code is, just how easy it is to understand and implement.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking so long to reply. I'll do my best to help you but I suspect this'll take a little back and forth.

Firstly, a complaint: I have a certain dislike for Hungarian notation.

Next up, a question: How exactly are you creating the user interface? Is that dynamically created somehow, or?
What exactly are you using the data class for, and how?

What kind of control are you using to get a float from the user? (not really important, I'm just curious)

Thirdly, how dug in are you to this approach? Do you have a large amount of legacy code using it, or could you feasibly change?

Finally, do you read all the user input for the data class at once, do you read whenever a value changes, or do you read individual values at different points in the program?

Onto the first couple of approaches you could use:

1. Just suck it up and create a conversion method:

   ```
    namespace Whatever.Path.Ui.ControlMarshalling
    {   
        public class Data
        {
            public string StageType { get; set; } 
            public float TankDepth { get; set; }
            public string Wire { get; set; }
        }

        // I dunno, probably derive this from some kind of UI element
        public class InputPane
        {
            public TextBox StageType;
            public SomeKindOfControl TankDepth;
            public TextBox Wire;

            // Not sure how you're triggering this, but from context I gather you read all values at once
            public Data ReadInput(){
                return new Data(){
                    StageType = StageType.Text,
                    TankDepth = TankDepth.Value,
                    Wire = Wire.Text
                };
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   The idea would then to keep an array (or other collection) of ten InputPanes, and then you can access the data from each simply as `arrayName[index].ReadInput()`. Rigid, easy to understand for the uninitiated, and fairly extendable without too much hassle.
2. Use reflection. This isn't nearly as elegant or maintainable and will likely lead to a lot of bugs if you implement it in such a way that involves hardcoded strings, but if you work something like this into your code it might help:

```
    Type type = typeof(clsMyClass);
    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("PropertyName");
    prop.SetValue(clsMyClassInstance, PropertyValue);
As before, I would recommend storing instances of `clsMyClass` in an array so you can access them as `clsMyClass[i]`.
```

Additionally, I would encourage you to rethink your approach if at all possible (doubly so if you're not at the very end of the project). Trying to get methods and properties by name in C# is really not great. There *is* a `dynamic` type, but using it you effectively miss out on all chance of type safety (if I recall correctly there are negative performance implications too, but TBH that's the least of the reasons for my hatred of it). Other ways (such as reflection) tend to result in confusing tangles of code in which nothing can be renamed without breaking stuff. This is all far worse if you mix string literals into the equation. C# is designed  for static typing, so if it's at all possible to work with that it will probably lead to better results (especially in the long-term).

Regarding this:

> don't care how efficient or "pretty" the code is, just how easy it is
> to understand and implement.

Typically code that's considered pretty is simple to understand and maintain, although on occasion it requires slightly more work to design and implement in the first place. Also, in most cases the language is designed so that elegant solutions tend to be more efficient (but there are definitely exceptions to this).

Let me know if either of these is helpful, and what other barriers to implementation you have.

Comment: This app is to dynamically create test sheets for the machines we build with the tests in a logical order.  There are up to 10 stages, which can be 1 of 3 types and may have several options.  The data is to store this information so, when finished, an optimized test procedure can be generated and printed.  The controls are a mix of buttons.visible and tabs with data entry for the different types and overall system.  Tabs are changed automatically by selected stage.  I am now using a data table to eliminate complications.  The variable names are my own convention.  Types are good.  Var is bad.

Comment: Phew, thank goodness you're not one of the ones who like to approach problems by eliminating type safety...would it be possible to design a data class for each of the three types of stage, and then store the results in a List? I say list simply because you mention "up to" 10, but if you know how many there are beforehand you could use an array too

Comment: I am doing the data for 10 and using a datatable. I'm self taught and cannot for the life of me figure out classes. It will have data for all 3 types in all 10 stages since it won't be much. Whether needed or not, the data will be there. Using a data grid I can easily know where any data for any stage is. Using class instances I can't easily access the data unless I hard code if statements for every possibility. Seems a little short sighted in my opinion. You should be able to access anything without specifically naming it in hard code like in my example with controls.

Comment: A datatable is a kind of input control, right? If I recall correctly that's easier than making individual input controls for each piece of data, but it's been a while. I would encourage you to really try to understand classes (maybe find a tutorial specidlfically for those concepts or something) and use them to the best of your ability in future projects until you really get the hang of good class (and program) design. That'll go a long way towards making you a good object-oriented programmer.